# Microsoft Solver Foundation Modulo Operator

Tags: c#, modulo, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to add a basic constraint to my solver foundation by doing the following:

```
model.AddConstraint("c1", x % y == 0);
```

I get a compile error saying "Operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Decision' and 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Decision'".

This makes sense since a lot of operators aren't supported. However, a lot of the operators that aren't supported (sin, cos, tan, etc.) are available as specific methods on the Model class such as below:

```
model.AddConstraint("c1", Model.Sum(x,y) == 0);
```

If I replace "Sum" with "Mod", there is no method available.

Any ideas on how to perform a modulo operation in Solver Foundation? According to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818505%28v=vs.93%29.aspx), it is supported.

I am going to start using reflector to dig through the code, but I figured I would post it on here also. If I find a solution, I will update my question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Mod at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff525341(v=vs.93).aspx, but here's a workaround:

```
Model.Floor(Model.Quotient(x,y))==Model.Ceiling(Model.Quotient(x,y))
```

This is only true if x/y is an integer, and so x%y==0.

There are also other ways of combining the allowed operators to check if it is divisible. My favorite (though I wouldn't recommend it because of floating point precision) is

```
Model.Sin(Math.PI*Model.Quotient(x,y))==0
```

Comment: That makes sense. This works when calling the Solve() method, but then doesn't work context.FindAllowedValues(bindings); I get an UnsolvableModelException saying "No solver could be found that can accept the model given the model type and directive(s)". I really need to get a list of all values that satisfy the condition. Do I need to specify another solver that can handle non-linear models?

Comment: @user1574360 Sorry, I don't know. Try the Sin workaround though, and see if that works. It could be that the non-smoothness of floor and ceiling are causing issue with that solver.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting, I wanted to write the exact same question at SO :-)

I found out that a Mod operator is defined for the OML language at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818505(v=vs.93).aspx.

There is an overload of the AddConstraint method, that accepts an expression string(I guess an OML expression?) instead of the Term. Unfortunately, I don't know the right formatting, but once we get the knack out of it, we would be able to use all of the other operators as well.

**EDIT**

It looks like not every OML expression described in API is working. For example,

```
SolverContext sc = SolverContext.GetContext();
Model m = sc.CreateModel();

m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0,10), "a"));
m.AddDecision(new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0, 10), "b"));

m.AddConstraint(null, "a > 0");
m.AddConstraint(null, "b == Plus[a,2]");
```

The Plus[x,y] in this case is working and the solver computes the following decision

a: 1,
b: 3

But if I replace the last constraint with this one

```
m.AddConstraint(null, "b == Mod[a,2]");
```

I get an OmlParseException ("Failed to parse OML model. Expression: Mod[a,2]."). I guess we are on our own here and purhaps the best thing we can do is sticking with the answer of user141603.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to use at first. The syntax is supposedly Mod[x,y], but that throws an error. I tried it for Plus[x,2] as well and that didn't work either so it's got to be the syntax that's wrong. Let me know if you find anything useful.